# can I use caret twoClassSummary for logLoss metric

Tags: r, r-caret

Is there any way to use `logLoss` metric with `twoClassSummary`? I've used `multiClassSummary` with `logLoss`. Using `multiClassSummary` with some methods like 'nnet' for two class problem with `logLoss` seems to throw the error:

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "'n' must be a positive integer >= 'x'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I find caret frustrating to use. My opinion is that trying to have such an all encompassing package, while a noble goal, makes it unwieldy.

I've coded up my own logloss and multi-class logloss functions, which you can find here. It has a dependency on caret for `CreateDataPartition`, but I'll probably remove that the next time I update the source code.

```
devtools::install_github("alexwhitworth/glmEnsemble")
```

An Example:

```
data(iris)
# indicator matrix of class membership
c_mat <- matrix(0, nrow=150, ncol=3)
c_mat[,1] <-ifelse(iris$Species == "setosa", 1, 0)
c_mat[,2] <-ifelse(iris$Species == "versicolor", 1, 0)
c_mat[,3] <-ifelse(iris$Species == "virginica", 1, 0)

# example predicted probability matrix
p_mat <- matrix(1/3, nrow=150, ncol=3)

# multiclass log-loss (I should make this exported this on the next update)
glmEnsemble:::multiclass_logloss(p_mat, c_mat)
[1] -1.098612
# two class log-loss
glmEnsemble::class_logloss(p_mat[,1], c_mat[,1])
[1] -0.3662041
```

Comment: As it may be, I still would like to get an answer to my original question. Caret has its problems but it saves a ton of time.